# How to make OAuth2 Authorization Request via POST to Custom API using Scribe

Tags: java, android, scribe

Hello fellow developers...

I am new to oauth2 and I found Scribe Java Library which suits my needs... but the problem is that I have my own oauth2 server which receives request via POST and user credentials are passed through PAYLOAD "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Here you can see sample request:
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RONP.png)

And when I try to implement my own ApiClass using documentation

> https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/Custom-Apis

and I noticed that client credentials are attached to url

```
private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://jimbo.com/oauth/authorize?token=%s";
```

which means authorization requests are made via GET :(

How to configure ApiClass properly to make POST request?

Thanks in advance :)

UPD: for the OAuth2 Server Side I am using

> github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server

Comment: Try using RestTemplate in android for making post, get or exchange type requests.

Comment: If you want, I can always put some samples, but there are lots of samples already available on net.

Comment: @WeareBorg Thank you for your answer:)  I was thinking about implementing my own library for OAuth2... Any help appreciated ^_^

Comment: That would have been brave.. :D

Comment: @WeareBorg btw) It would be great, If you could provide some samples :)

Comment: Why dont you post the server side which is in POST, and the code you have until now for your client side... Edit your main post and paste it there.

Comment: @WeareBorg for the server side I am using https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server :) and for client side I have done nothing))) just Empty project where I imported bunch of OAuth2 client libraries) and testing them)

Comment: I have made a sample method for you, here it is with some comments : http://pastebin.com/q2kgpcXx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the result I deleted Scribe from my project... and implemented own method for getting access token...

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/oauth2/token");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", clientID));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", clientSecret));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        JSONObject json_auth = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        String token = json_auth.getString("access_token");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```